# PHP Array append values

Tags: php, opencart

I am having a problem appending a few options to an array of modules. I am using Opencart and trying to extend a module by adding an image. To do this and ensure that the code will not break anything in the future I wanted to add to the array instead of replace it.

This is the code I have so far:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['special_module'])) {
    $modules = $this->request->post['special_module'];
} elseif ($this->config->get('special_module')) { 
    $modules = $this->config->get('special_module');
}

$this->load->model('tool/image');

foreach ($modules as $module) {
    if (isset($module['image']) && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $module['image'])) {
        $image = $module['image'];
    } else {
        $image = 'no_image.jpg';
    }           

    array_push($module, array(
        'image'        => $image,
        'thumb'        => $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 100, 100)
    )); 
} 
print_r($modules);exit;
$this->data['modules'] = $modules;
```

Print Array, no image or thumb:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image_width] => 307
            [image_height] => 234
            [layout_id] => 1
            [position] => column_right
            [status] => 1
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

)
```

When I do array_push do I need to assign this back to the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$module is being overwritten by the foreach() loop every time it iterates. So your push is basically a null-op, becaus foreach will destroy the previous $module (that you pushed to) with the next $module value coming out of $modules. You'd need something more like this:

```
foreach($modules as &$module) {
    ...
    $module['image'] = $image;
    $module['thumb'] = ...;
}
```

The `&` before $module in the foreach turns it into a reference, so any modifications to `$module` within the loop will modify the original element in $modules, rather than a copy which would get trashed on every iteration.

Comment: Brilliant, there is so much I still have to learn as PHP. Are there any books/guides you would recommend to learn more about references? When I do a Google search all I can find it actual references to PHP.

Comment: Most online stuff you'll find for php tutorials is badly out of date (talking about PHP 4 and early 5s), hideously crappy in quality, and/or flat-out wrong. Especially avoid anything from [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). The [PHP site](http://php.net) is actually pretty good, and the comments in the function reference section are frequently quite helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

$module, in your foreach loop is a copy of the contents. You will need to access it by reference, or push back into the actual array $modules.

Try modifying the foreach signature to the following:

```
foreach ($modules as &$module) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try using array_merge instead of array_push

```
array_merge($module, array(
    'image'        => $image,
    'thumb'        => $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 100, 100)
));
```

edit:

also, as print_r outputs the correct should be `array_merge($module[0], array(...));`